# Rails - retrieve result of method call from controller in a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a call to my json end point to give me back all the Assignments WHERE the volunteer_shift.date is between params[:start] and params[:end]

Is there a way I can do that in the index method of assignments_controller?

I currently have this in the index method of my controller but it is exploding in my face...

assignments_controller.rb

```
def index
  @assignments = Assignment.where(volunteer_shift.date: params[:start]..params[:end])  <--- HOW To DO this?
end
```

Here is what my assignments model looks like...

assignment.rb

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :volunteer_shift

  def event_date
    self.volunteer_shift.date
  end
...
end
```

In my Volunteer_shift model I have a "date" method

volunteer_shift.rb

```
class VolunteerShift < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments
  belongs_to :volunteer_event
...
  def date
    self.volunteer_event.date
  end
end
```

is there a way I can get back all the Assignments WHERE the volunteer_shift.date (or assignment.event_date) is between params[:start] and params[:end]?

Note: Rails 5

Comment: You try this sql: Assignments.where('volunteer_shift.date BETWEEN ? AND ?', params[:start], params[:end])

Comment: Says this now: "PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "volunteer_shift"

NOTE: the "date" column physically sits in volunteer_event. volunter_event is a column in volunteer_shift

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly use a method as a active record argument since rails basically uses SQL to retrieve those datas, So, you have to deal with attributes

You can use [ActiveRecord#joins](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins) to join the tables and then use your "where" statement, like;

```ruby
 Assignment.joins(volunteer_shift: :volunteer_event).where(volunteer_shifts: {volunteer_events: {date: params[:start]..params[:end] }})
```

***Remember***; "joins" arguments must be the relationship name, while "where" arguments must be the table name

---

If you wish to hide all this code, you can create a [scope](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope) to do it, like;

*assignment.rb*

```ruby
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :volunteer_shift

  scope :date_range, lambda { |range|
    joins(volunteer_shift: :volunteer_event)
      .where(volunteer_shifts: { volunteer_events: { date: range } })
  }

  def event_date
    self.volunteer_shift.date
  end
end
```

and call with;

```ruby
Assignment.date_range(params[:start]..params[:end])
```

Comment: Almost. The arguments to `joins` are the names of the associations which don't necessarily need to be the same as the model name.

Comment: Corrected, thank you